# Tensorflow object detection API: Custom VGG 16 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim, vgg-net

I am in the process of creating a Custom VGG model as a feature extractor of Faster RCNN model in Tensorflow object detection API. As mentioned on in the document https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md the feature extractor code consists of `extract_proposal_features` and  `extract_classifier_features`. I am using TF slim code of creating the convolution layers (since they Tensorflow team uses it). As a reference please find the model structure of VGG 16 returned using by TF slim

```
      ([('vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv1/conv1_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 64) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv1/conv1_2',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv1/conv1_2/Relu:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 64) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/vgg_16/pool1',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/pool1/MaxPool:0' shape=(?, 112, 112, 64) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv2/conv2_1',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv2/conv2_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 112, 112, 128) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv2/conv2_2',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv2/conv2_2/Relu:0' shape=(?, 112, 112, 128) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/vgg_16/pool2',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/pool2/MaxPool:0' shape=(?, 56, 56, 128) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv3/conv3_1',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv3/conv3_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 56, 56, 256) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv3/conv3_2',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv3/conv3_2/Relu:0' shape=(?, 56, 56, 256) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv3/conv3_3',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv3/conv3_3/Relu:0' shape=(?, 56, 56, 256) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/vgg_16/pool3',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/pool3/MaxPool:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 256) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv4/conv4_1',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv4/conv4_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv4/conv4_2',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv4/conv4_2/Relu:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv4/conv4_3',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv4/conv4_3/Relu:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/vgg_16/pool4',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/pool4/MaxPool:0' shape=(?, 14, 14, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv5/conv5_1',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv5/conv5_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 14, 14, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv5/conv5_2',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv5/conv5_2/Relu:0' shape=(?, 14, 14, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/conv5/conv5_3',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/conv5/conv5_3/Relu:0' shape=(?, 14, 14, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/vgg_16/pool5',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/pool5/MaxPool:0' shape=(?, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/fc6',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/fc6/Relu:0' shape=(?, 1, 1, 4096) dtype=float32>),
        ('vgg_16/fc7',
         <tf.Tensor 'vgg_16/vgg_16/fc7/Relu:0' shape=(?, 1, 1, 4096) dtype=float32>)])
```

My question is that, which convolution layer needs to be included and returned in `extract_proposal_features` method and which convolution layers needs to be included and returned in `extract_classifier_features`. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed vgg slim code to get the right tensor.

```
def vgg_16(inputs,
       num_classes=1000,
       is_training=True,
       dropout_keep_prob=0.5,
       spatial_squeeze=True,
       scope='vgg_16',
       fc_conv_padding='VALID',
       global_pool=False):
"""Oxford Net VGG 16-Layers version D Example.

Note: All the fully_connected layers have been transformed to conv2d layers.
      To use in classification mode, resize input to 224x224.

Args:
  inputs: a tensor of size [batch_size, height, width, channels].
  num_classes: number of predicted classes. If 0 or None, the logits layer is
    omitted and the input features to the logits layer are returned instead.
  is_training: whether or not the model is being trained.
  dropout_keep_prob: the probability that activations are kept in the dropout
    layers during training.
  spatial_squeeze: whether or not should squeeze the spatial dimensions of the
    outputs. Useful to remove unnecessary dimensions for classification.
  scope: Optional scope for the variables.
  fc_conv_padding: the type of padding to use for the fully connected layer
    that is implemented as a convolutional layer. Use 'SAME' padding if you
    are applying the network in a fully convolutional manner and want to
    get a prediction map downsampled by a factor of 32 as an output.
    Otherwise, the output prediction map will be (input / 32) - 6 in case of
    'VALID' padding.
  global_pool: Optional boolean flag. If True, the input to the classification
    layer is avgpooled to size 1x1, for any input size. (This is not part
    of the original VGG architecture.)

Returns:
  net: the output of the logits layer (if num_classes is a non-zero integer),
    or the input to the logits layer (if num_classes is 0 or None).
  end_points: a dict of tensors with intermediate activations.
"""
with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'vgg_16', [inputs]) as sc:
    end_points_collection = sc.original_name_scope + '_end_points'
    # Collect outputs for conv2d, fully_connected and max_pool2d.
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected, slim.max_pool2d],
                        outputs_collections=end_points_collection):
        net = slim.repeat(inputs, 2, slim.conv2d, 64, [3, 3], scope='conv1')
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool1')
        net = slim.repeat(net, 2, slim.conv2d, 128, [3, 3], scope='conv2')
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool2')
        net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 256, [3, 3], scope='conv3')
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool3')
        net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 512, [3, 3], scope='conv4')
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool4')
        net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 512, [3, 3], scope='conv5')
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool5')

        # Convert end_points_collection into a end_point dict.
        end_points = slim.utils.convert_collection_to_dict(end_points_collection)

        end_points['head'] = net

        # Use conv2d instead of fully_connected layers.
        net = slim.conv2d(net, 4096, [7, 7], padding=fc_conv_padding, scope='fc6')
        net = slim.dropout(net, dropout_keep_prob, is_training=is_training,
                           scope='dropout6')
        net = slim.conv2d(net, 4096, [1, 1], scope='fc7')

        if global_pool:
            net = tf.reduce_mean(net, [1, 2], keep_dims=True, name='global_pool')
            end_points['global_pool'] = net
        if num_classes:
            net = slim.dropout(net, dropout_keep_prob, is_training=is_training,
                               scope='dropout7')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, num_classes, [1, 1],
                              activation_fn=None,
                              normalizer_fn=None,
                              scope='fc8')
            if spatial_squeeze and num_classes is not None:
                net = tf.squeeze(net, [1, 2], name='fc8/squeezed')
            end_points[sc.name + '/fc8'] = net
        return net, end_points
```

`end_points['head']` = net is the tensor use to extract_proposal_features.

```
def _extract_proposal_features(self, preprocessed_inputs, scope):
    """Extracts first stage RPN features.

    Args:
      preprocessed_inputs: A [batch, height, width, channels] float32 tensor
        representing a batch of images.
      scope: A scope name.

    Returns:
      rpn_feature_map: A tensor with shape [batch, height, width, depth]
    Raises:
      InvalidArgumentError: If the spatial size of `preprocessed_inputs`
        (height or width) is less than 33.
      ValueError: If the created network is missing the required activation.
    """

    preprocessed_inputs.get_shape().assert_has_rank(4)
    shape_assert = tf.Assert(
        tf.logical_and(tf.greater_equal(tf.shape(preprocessed_inputs)[1], 33),
                       tf.greater_equal(tf.shape(preprocessed_inputs)[2], 33)),
        ['image size must at least be 33 in both height and width.'])

    with tf.control_dependencies([shape_assert]):
        with tf.variable_scope('vgg_16', 'vgg_16', reuse=self._reuse_weights):
            _, activations = vgg.vgg_16(
                preprocessed_inputs,
                scope=scope)

    return activations['head']
```

and

```
def _extract_box_classifier_features(self, proposal_feature_maps, scope):
    """Extracts second stage box classifier features.

    Args:
      proposal_feature_maps: A 4-D float tensor with shape
        [batch_size * self.max_num_proposals, crop_height, crop_width, depth]
        representing the feature map cropped to each proposal.
      scope: A scope name (unused).

    Returns:
      proposal_classifier_features: A 4-D float tensor with shape
        [batch_size * self.max_num_proposals, height, width, depth]
        representing box classifier features for each proposal.
    """
    net = proposal_feature_maps

    with tf.variable_scope('vgg_16', reuse=self._reuse_weights):
        with slim.arg_scope(
                [slim.conv2d],
                stride=1,
                padding='VALID'):
            # Use conv2d instead of fully_connected layers.
            fc6 = slim.conv2d(net, 4096, [7, 7], padding='VALID', scope='fc6')
            if self._is_training:
                fc6 = slim.dropout(fc6, keep_prob=0.5, is_training=True,
                                   scope='dropout6')
            fc7 = slim.conv2d(fc6, 4096, [1, 1], scope='fc7')
            if self._is_training:
                fc7 = slim.dropout(fc7, keep_prob=0.5, is_training=True,
                                   scope='dropout7')
    proposal_classifier_features = fc7

    return proposal_classifier_features
```

I do like this. I do not know if it's the correct way :)

This is my test code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from models import faster_rcnn_vgg_16_feature_extractor as faster_rcnn_vgg_16


class FasterRcnnVgg16FeatureExtractorTest(tf.test.TestCase):

def _build_feature_extractor(self, first_stage_features_stride):
    return faster_rcnn_vgg_16.FasterRCNNVgg16FeatureExtractor(
        is_training=False,
        first_stage_features_stride=first_stage_features_stride,
        weight_decay=0.0005)

def test_extract_proposal_features_returns_expected_size(self):
    feature_extractor = self._build_feature_extractor(
        first_stage_features_stride=16)
    preprocessed_inputs = tf.random_uniform(
        [4, 224, 224, 3], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32)
    rpn_feature_map = feature_extractor.extract_proposal_features(
        preprocessed_inputs, scope='TestScope')
    features_shape = tf.shape(rpn_feature_map)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with self.test_session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        features_shape_out = sess.run(features_shape)
        self.assertAllEqual(features_shape_out, [4, 7, 7, 512])

def test_extract_proposal_features_stride_eight(self):
    feature_extractor = self._build_feature_extractor(
        first_stage_features_stride=8)
    preprocessed_inputs = tf.random_uniform(
        [4, 224, 224, 3], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32)
    rpn_feature_map = feature_extractor.extract_proposal_features(
        preprocessed_inputs, scope='TestScope')
    features_shape = tf.shape(rpn_feature_map)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with self.test_session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        features_shape_out = sess.run(features_shape)
        self.assertAllEqual(features_shape_out, [4, 7, 7, 512])

def test_extract_proposal_features_half_size_input(self):
    feature_extractor = self._build_feature_extractor(
        first_stage_features_stride=16)
    preprocessed_inputs = tf.random_uniform(
        [1, 112, 112, 3], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32)
    rpn_feature_map = feature_extractor.extract_proposal_features(
        preprocessed_inputs, scope='TestScope')
    features_shape = tf.shape(rpn_feature_map)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with self.test_session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        features_shape_out = sess.run(features_shape)
        self.assertAllEqual(features_shape_out, [1, 4, 4, 512])

def test_extract_proposal_features_dies_on_invalid_stride(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        self._build_feature_extractor(first_stage_features_stride=99)

def test_extract_proposal_features_dies_on_very_small_images(self):
    feature_extractor = self._build_feature_extractor(
        first_stage_features_stride=16)
    preprocessed_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (4, None, None, 3))
    rpn_feature_map = feature_extractor.extract_proposal_features(
        preprocessed_inputs, scope='TestScope')
    features_shape = tf.shape(rpn_feature_map)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with self.test_session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        with self.assertRaises(tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError):
            sess.run(
                features_shape,
                feed_dict={preprocessed_inputs: np.random.rand(4, 32, 32, 3)})

def test_extract_proposal_features_dies_with_incorrect_rank_inputs(self):
    feature_extractor = self._build_feature_extractor(
        first_stage_features_stride=16)
    preprocessed_inputs = tf.random_uniform(
        [224, 224, 3], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32)
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        feature_extractor.extract_proposal_features(
            preprocessed_inputs, scope='TestScope')

def test_extract_box_classifier_features_returns_expected_size(self):
    feature_extractor = self._build_feature_extractor(
        first_stage_features_stride=16)
    proposal_feature_maps = tf.random_uniform(
        [3, 7, 7, 512], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32)
    proposal_classifier_features = (
        feature_extractor.extract_box_classifier_features(
            proposal_feature_maps, scope='TestScope'))
    features_shape = tf.shape(proposal_classifier_features)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with self.test_session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        features_shape_out = sess.run(features_shape)
        self.assertAllEqual(features_shape_out, [3, 1, 1, 4096])


if __name__ == '__main__':
      tf.test.main()
```

Comment: Hey Ricci. I did the same thing. But in `_extract_box_classifier_features` method the proposal classifier features = fc 7 threw an error stating, global pooling cannot be used next to a fully connected layer. Did u encounter this. So I actually replaced the code.

Comment: I trained the model on openimages with no error. I used tensorflow 1.4.1. The pretrained vgg16 is from slim vgg_16_2016_08_28.tar.gz . I lost my training evaluation so i can't post an image. I needed to modify other python file inside the api to make it work (otherwise the new model is not seen by the api).

Comment: Yes Ricci. Thanks for your comments. What meta architect did you use, 1.SSD 2.FastRCNN 3. FasterRCNN.  I tried with FasterRCNN and it threw me an error. So I removed the FCNN and just retained the CNN part for the feature extractor.

Comment: i used Faster R-CCN. i add the test class to the answer.

Comment: From your test class, I could see that my mode meta-architecture is different. Thanks for the share. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is additional answer for whom seeking for SSD architecture, the Tensorflow Object Detection API 1 has include `vgg` architecture from `slim` folder, we can import it `from nets import vgg` directly. I have just only tried with SSD architecture. I follow the ssd-mobilenet config to create respective models from 2 layers 'fc7' and 'conv4_3' as stated in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf). Then, save your new `SSD-VGG16_feature_extractor.py` inside `models` folder.

**Notice** For a correct matching with the `vgg` in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf), you should change 4096 to 1024 and kernel size `[7,7]` to `[3,3]` for correct depth features https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/vgg.py#L206-L209

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tf_slim as slim

from object_detection.meta_architectures import ssd_meta_arch
from object_detection.models import feature_map_generators
from object_detection.utils import ops
from object_detection.utils import shape_utils
from nets import vgg


class SSDVgg16FeatureExtractor(ssd_meta_arch.SSDFeatureExtractor):
  """SSD Feature Extractor using Vgg16 features."""

  def __init__(self,
               is_training,
               depth_multiplier,
               min_depth,
               pad_to_multiple,
               conv_hyperparams_fn,
               reuse_weights=None,
               use_explicit_padding=False,
               use_depthwise=False,
               override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams=False):
    """Vgg16 Feature Extractor for SSD Models.
    Args:
      is_training: whether the network is in training mode.
      depth_multiplier: float depth multiplier for feature extractor.
      min_depth: minimum feature extractor depth.
      pad_to_multiple: the nearest multiple to zero pad the input height and
        width dimensions to.
      conv_hyperparams_fn: A function to construct tf slim arg_scope for conv2d
        and separable_conv2d ops in the layers that are added on top of the
        base feature extractor.
      reuse_weights: Whether to reuse variables. Default is None.
      use_explicit_padding: Whether to use explicit padding when extracting
        features. Default is False.
      use_depthwise: Whether to use depthwise convolutions. Default is False.
      num_layers: Number of SSD layers.
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: Whether to override
        hyperparameters of the base feature extractor with the one from
        `conv_hyperparams_fn`.
    Raises:
      ValueError: If `override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams` is False.
    """
    super(SSDVgg16FeatureExtractor, self).__init__(
        is_training=is_training,
        depth_multiplier=depth_multiplier,
        min_depth=min_depth,
        pad_to_multiple=pad_to_multiple,
        conv_hyperparams_fn=conv_hyperparams_fn,
        reuse_weights=reuse_weights,
        use_explicit_padding=use_explicit_padding,
        use_depthwise=use_depthwise,
        override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams=
        override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams)
    if not self._override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams:
      raise ValueError('SSD Vgg16 feature extractor always uses'
                       'scope returned by `conv_hyperparams_fn` for both the '
                       'base feature extractor and the additional layers '
                       'added since there is no arg_scope defined for the base '
                       'feature extractor.')

  def preprocess(self, resized_inputs):
    """SSD preprocessing.
    Maps pixel values to the range [-1, 1].
    Args:
      resized_inputs: a [batch, height, width, channels] float tensor
        representing a batch of images.
    Returns:
      preprocessed_inputs: a [batch, height, width, channels] float tensor
        representing a batch of images.
    """
    return (2.0 / 255.0) * resized_inputs - 1.0

  def extract_features(self, preprocessed_inputs):
    """Extract features from preprocessed inputs.
    Args:
      preprocessed_inputs: a [batch, height, width, channels] float tensor
        representing a batch of images.
    Returns:
      feature_maps: a list of tensors where the ith tensor has shape
        [batch, height_i, width_i, depth_i]
    """
    preprocessed_inputs = shape_utils.check_min_image_dim(
        33, preprocessed_inputs)

    feature_map_layout = {
        'from_layer': ['FeatureExtractor/vgg_16/conv4/conv4_3', 'FeatureExtractor/vgg_16/fc7', '', '', '', ''],
        'layer_depth': [-1, -1, 512, 256, 256, 128],
        'use_explicit_padding': self._use_explicit_padding,
        'use_depthwise': self._use_depthwise,
    }
    with slim.arg_scope(self._conv_hyperparams_fn()):
      with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):
        _, image_features = vgg.vgg_16(
            ops.pad_to_multiple(preprocessed_inputs, self._pad_to_multiple),
            num_classes=0)
    print("Available output head: ")
    print([k for k,v in image_features.items()])
    with slim.arg_scope(self._conv_hyperparams_fn()):
      feature_maps = feature_map_generators.multi_resolution_feature_maps(
        feature_map_layout=feature_map_layout,
        depth_multiplier=self._depth_multiplier,
        min_depth=self._min_depth,
        insert_1x1_conv=True,
        image_features=image_features)

    return list(feature_maps.values())
```

Then, you just need to update `'ssd_vgg16': SSDVgg16FeatureExtractor` in `SSD_FEATURE_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_MAP` dict in `builder/model_builder.py` to complete the model.

I have tested and it works like charm

```
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.195851
I1223 18:19:21.963316 139974845604416 basic_session_run_hooks.py:692] global_step/sec: 0.195851
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.674446, step = 700 (510.592 sec)
I1223 18:19:21.964789 139974845604416 basic_session_run_hooks.py:260] loss = 3.674446, step = 700 (510.592 sec)
```

Comment: full implemenation is available at https://github.com/dtlam26/BIE-Active_Learning/blob/main/custom_backbone/ssd-vgg16_tf_v1/vgg.py